# Set PYTHONPATH for local Jupyter Notebook in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, pythonpath

I'm using Visual Studio 1.39.2 on Windows 10. I'm very happy that you can run Jupyter Notebook natively through VS Code as of October this year (2019), but one thing I don't get right is how to set my `PYTHONPATH` prior to booting up a local Jupyter server.

What I want is to be able to import a certain module which is located in another folder (because the module is compiled from C++ code). When I run a normal Python debugging session, I found out that I can set environment variables of the integrated terminal, via the setting `terminal.integrated.env.linux`. Thus, I set my `PYTHNPATH` through this option when debugging as normal. But when running a Jupyter Notebook, the local Jupyter server doesn't seem to run in the integrated terminal (at least not from what I can see), so it doesn't have the `PYTHONPATH` set.

My question is then, how can I automatically have the `PYTHONPATH` set for my local Jupyter Notebook servers in VS Code?

Answer (score 19):

I found that you can set this for Jupyter notebooks in the `settings.json` file.

```
{
    "jupyter.notebookFileRoot": "/path/to/your/module/root"
}
```

Edit: Or, to set it at your workspace root more generically:

```
{
    "jupyter.notebookFileRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the PYTHONPATH point to the Python executable? This seems to be configuring the dir where the notebook is to be found, not which Python executable  Jupyter should use. Isn't that what OP is asking?

Comment: @user2739472 [not exactly](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH).

Answer (score 6):

I'm a developer on this extension. If you have a specific path for module resolution we provide a setting for the Jupyter features called:

Python->Data Science: Run Startup Commands

That setting will run a series of python instructions in any Jupyter session context when starting up. In that setting you could just append that path that you need to sys.path directly and then it will run and add that path every time you start up a notebook or an Interactive Window session.

Comment: I can't get this to work. I test it simply by assigning a variable in the startup commands like `hi = 42` and then create a new blank Jupyter notebook via the command palette with the line `print(hi)`. Then, if I try to run the notebook, the variable is not defined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This worked for me by adding `sys.path.append('./src') where src is the folder I'm putting my Python, but it feels like a really clunky way to "inject" my project's source code into the Jupyter environment. @IanHuff are there any  improvements to this being considered?

Comment: @janh Sorry for the slow reply. I'm not on SO that often. If you would like you could create a github issue for this suggestion here. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues. That's the spot that we track and triage all our work items.

Comment: @IanHuff I added an answer I think may be an evolution of the feature you describe? I couldn't find the `Run Startup Commands` or any other Data Science settings at this time.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem importing a python module developed in C++. I added the relative path to my build directory from my notebook to the `.env` file in my workspace folder.

```
PYTHONPATH=build/lib:../../../build/lib
```

The path from the workspace folder is `build/lib`, from my notebook folder is `../../../build/lib`, and the path separator is `:`.

(The reason I have the `build/lib` path, from the workspace folder, is for pytest.)

Comment: Tested on linux, not on windows. Path separator might be different on windows?